# dotnet equivalent of ObjectWeb's ASM to visit dot net *.dll contents

Tags: java, .net

I was just wondering if theres an equivalent that enables one to visit, update class files within a dot net assembly...

Comment: +1 There might be one given there are decompilers. http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: From what i can tell it doesnt appear to have an API but is a IDE plugin.